# Twig & symfony, use a variable in a {% javascript %} tag

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I have this very sample twig template :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>my title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% javascripts '@jquery' '@bootstrap_js' output='javascript.js' %}
            <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
        <p>its the name of the first js file : {{ file_js1 }}</p> {# print '@javascript1label_defined_from_asseticconfig' #}
        <p>its the name of the second js file : {{ file_js2 }}</p> {# print '@javascript2label_defined_from_asseticconfig' #}
    </body>
</html>
```

I want add the {{ file_js1 }} and the {{ file_js2 }} in the {% javascript %} , how can I do that ? (for manage dynamically javascript file include). I do several tries but I didn't find the good syntax with twig..

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to include the files, or dynamically include them?  If you are just trying to include them, make sure they are in your bundle and use:

```
<script src="{{ asset('path/name/goes/here.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake in my initial post. {{ file_js1}} and {{ file_js2 }} return me '@js1label_defined_from_asseticconfig' and '@js2label_defined_from_asseticconfig', not the /path/to/file. So, I want find how add these twig variable into {% javascript %} (next to '@jquery' and '@bootstrap.js' ) .Ill correct my initial post !

Comment: Using your code solution doesn't work; the HTML doesn't include even the script tag. I'm not seeing why. We don't have assetic installed, and it isn't required for other twig files in the repo to have that tag inclusion work, but they're slightly different contexts that I'm not understanding yet. I'm ashamed to say which version of Symfony we're using, but it's not 5.4 or 4.4.

Comment: Hey @SteveExdia - this answer was from quite a bit ago and I haven't used Symphony much since then. This solution seems to be assetic specific from what I can tell just googling https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/frontend/assetic/asset_management.html#introducing-assetic

Comment: @ckifer Looks like the issue is our Symfony was on a previous version that came with assetic, and the upgrade removed it, and now the previously-made output is basically orphaned but not in danger... I'm sure there's some sort of economic analogy here, but I won't even try to come up with one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is more related to assetic, but if what you really want is to add a variable to have it available in twig you need to do:

```
twig:
    globals:
        my_parameter: '%whatever_parameter%'
```

And then you can do in your twig template:

```
{{ my_parameter }}
```

Comment: For some reason our repo doesn't have `twig:` in it anywhere. Can you state a documentation page referencing this, of the version of Symfony you meant?

Comment: the current doc for doing this is described here (but it is defined the same way):
https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#global-variables

You probably should find your twig config at config/packages/twig.yaml